# Does Django run in single thread by default？

Tags: django

By reading the code, I found it seems that Django run in single thread by default.

However, when I use sleep(15) in my view function and open two web to request my function. They return the response almost at the same time!

so, I do not know why does it happened……

my Django version is 1.9

Comment: You are right, [dev server] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server) is running your code in one thread

Comment: Are you using "runserver"? Or a full web server?

Answer (score 20):

Django itself does not determine whether it runs in one or more threads. This is the job of the server running Django.

The development server used to be single-threaded, but in recent versions it has been made multithreaded. Other servers such as Apache/mod_wsgi, gunicorn, or uwsgi, have their own defaults and can be configured in a number of ways; often they use multiple processes rather than threads.

Comment: Is there a reason why they choose to use processes over threads?

Comment: At least since version 1.7 runserver is multithreaded by default. See [--nothreading](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-runserver-nothreading) in the Django-Docs.

Comment: @Algorithmatic I guess because python is single threaded, and each request can be separated into a different process, no need to share state (but just a wild guess)

Comment: Would django database queries wotk correctly if Model get's queried from different threads?